# removeEventListener, how to do it in special case

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```
grabbale.addEventListener("leap-hand-grab", function(e){
if (e.state === "grab") {
            console.log("grabbed");
} else if (e.state === "release") {
            console.log("release");
} else if (e.state === "move") {
    if (stopGrab == 0) {
        grabbale.style.left = e.x - (grabbale.offsetWidth/2)+ "px";
        grabbale.style.top = e.y - (grabbale.offsetHeight/2)+ "px";
    } else {
        $("#foo").css({
        "color": "red"
        });
    }
}
```

})

what I need is to **remove** eventListener using *removeEventListener*, but it require two arguments, the *event* and the *function*.
In my case the *function* haven't a name, and the *event* is the *drag* of **grabbale** element...
How can I do what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can usea a named function instead, which is the same thing only the anonymous function now has a name.

```
grabbale.addEventListener("leap-hand-grab", grabListener);

function grabListener(e){
    if (e.state === "grab") {
        console.log("grabbed");
    } else if (e.state === "release") {
        console.log("release");
    } else if (e.state === "move") {
        if (stopGrab == 0) {
            grabbale.style.left = e.x - (grabbale.offsetWidth/2)+ "px";
            grabbale.style.top = e.y - (grabbale.offsetHeight/2)+ "px";
    } else {
        $("#foo").css({
        "color": "red"
        });
    }
}
```

And for removal just use

```
grabbale.removeEventListener("leap-hand-grab", grabListener);
```

Where you need to remove the event.

Some extra links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression

Comment: Perfect, thanx!

Answer (score 0):

```
grabbale.addEventListener("leap-hand-grab", react);
function react(e){
  if (e.state === "grab") {
        console.log("grabbed");
   } else if (e.state === "release") {
        console.log("release");
   } else if (e.state === "move") {
  if (stopGrab == 0) {
    grabbale.style.left = e.x - (grabbale.offsetWidth/2)+ "px";
    grabbale.style.top = e.y - (grabbale.offsetHeight/2)+ "px";
    grabbale.removeEventListener("leap-hand-grab",react);
 } else {
    $("#foo").css({
    "color": "red"
    });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Same solution, same thanx... :-)